# Where is Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I've verified that `Entity Framework 6 Tools` is installed as suggested in other answers on this site, but `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` never shows up in the `New Items/Data` list. I've also tried installing the `.NET CORE 2.0 SDK` as other answers have suggested to no avail.

To be clear, I'm not creating a `.NET CORE` application, I'm just trying to make a class library based on `.NET framework 4.6`. I created the project via `.NET Standard` and selected `Class Library (.NET Standard)`.

I just need to install EF so I can do a code first generation from my existing SQL Server DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use *.NET Standard*, select a *.NET Framework* project type.

.NET Standard is an abstract "Core *or* Framework" option, as if the naming wasn't confusing enough.